# How get jsonp from remote server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Please help get jsonp-data from remote server:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function readresponse(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
    (function(){
        var src = 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#?callback=readresponse';
        var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
        script.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    })();   
});
```

But chrome browser tab 'network' display 200 status and correct json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the content your src url is returning you will see that it's a JSON and not JSONP. If it were to be JSONP your src should be:

```
var src = 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema&callback=readresponse'
```

and the data it would return would be wrapped as:

```
readresponse({...})
```

instead of just

```
{...}
```

which is why you receive the parse error.

---

You can find out more on this topic reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).